# ListView ItemTemplate and ItemsSource don't show expected value

Tags: wpf, listview, itemtemplate

I got a Problem with the following code:

```
FolderBrowserDialog ofd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        ofd.Description = "Wählen Sie bitte den Ordner mit den Videodateien die Sie verschieben und umbenennen wollen...";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
            string path = ofd.SelectedPath;
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path)) {
                files.Add(new FileStatus(file, new FileInfo(file).Length));
            }
        }
```

The Code of the FileStatus object is:

```
public FileStatus(string filename, long filesize, long currentsize = 0) {
        this.currentsize = currentsize;
        this.filename = filename;
        this.filesize = filesize;
    }
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public long filesize { get; set; }
    public long currentsize { get; set; }
    public double percent {
        get {
            return (currentsize / filesize) * 100;
        }
    }
```

The XAML of the ListView is:

```
<ListView Name="lb_data" Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource fileStatusTemp}">
    </ListView>
```

The XAML of fileStatusTemp:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="fileStatusTemp">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=filename}" ></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The ItemSource-property is set in the constructor of the window:

```
lb_data.ItemSource = files;
```

Thanks to KDiTraglia, for the advice :)
So the Problem is that when I run this code it doesn't displays the filename. It just shows nothing.
In another project a similiar piece of code works...
I hope you can help me :)
Greetings Knerd

Comment: If you break point on this line lb_data.ItemSource = files;
does files contain valid items that have filenames?

Comment: Yes, and also lb_data.Items contains the same objects in the list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an itemssource="{binding ??}" in your list view.  I am also skeptical as to whether this line is working as you intend...

```
DataContext="{Binding}"
```

Edit:

I copied this all into a test project and it works fine, here's my entire project verbatim, maybe I did something small.

dowhilefor makes a good point about INotifyPropertyChanged, my code works on load, but would not work if the files were added from an event other than the constructor.  To fix this easily, just change List to ObservableCollection (don't forget to include 'using System.Collections.ObjectModel').  I updated my code below.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<FileStatus> files { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        files = new ObservableCollection<FileStatus>();
        lb_data.ItemsSource = files;

        FolderBrowserDialog ofd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        ofd.Description = "Wählen Sie bitte den Ordner mit den Videodateien die Sie verschieben und umbenennen wollen...";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = ofd.SelectedPath;
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                files.Add(new FileStatus(file, new FileInfo(file).Length));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
<Window x:Class="WPFtest5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="fileStatusTemp">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=filename}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListView Name="lb_data" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource fileStatusTemp}"/>
</Window>
```

-

```
public class FileStatus
{
    public FileStatus(string filename, long filesize, long currentsize = 0)
    {
        this.currentsize = currentsize;
        this.filename = filename;
        this.filesize = filesize;
    }
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public long filesize { get; set; }
    public long currentsize { get; set; }
    public double percent
    {
        get
        {
            return (currentsize / filesize) * 100;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the way I did it last time. I forgot to say that the itemsource is set in the constructor of the Window.

Comment: @Knerd i don't know why this shouldn't work. The only thing i miss in this code is the implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. But this should at least work once. And yes, remove the DataContext="{Binding}" this does absolutely nothing. The datacontext is already inherited and doesn't need to be set explicitly in this case.

Comment: Updated code to account for INotifyPropertyChanged, I suspect that's the actual problem, though it is unclear what datatype the OP's 'files' is from the code posted

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged didn't changed anything.

Comment: Observable collection implements INotifyPropertyChanged by default whenever things are added / removed